# Android Handler() Runnable , queue the Runnables up

Tags: android, handler, runnable

Hello my fellow programmers :)
I call the function waitRunnable(int seconds, int startId) 4 times every time I click a button in my application. So waitRunnable() should just wait a variable amount of time and the time is set by a parameter seconds. But they run all at the same time so if the longest waitRunnable gets 10 seconds to wait and the other 3 waitRunnables wait less time then all 4 waitRunnables finish after 10 seconds but the first one should finish and just then the second one should be started so the total amount of time would be the sum of all parameters. I hope this is not to bad explained.

In love your jason <3 Thx for help :)

```
package com.example.Uebung10;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.os.Handler;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Created by Jason on 14.01.2016.
 */
public class MyService extends Service {
    final String LOG_TAG = "myServiceLogs";
    Handler h = new Handler();
    List<String> finishedTasksInTheLast60Sec = new ArrayList<>();
    ExecutorService es;
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sendBroadcast(finishedTasksInTheLast60Sec);
            h.postDelayed(this, 60000);
            finishedTasksInTheLast60Sec = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    };

    private void waitRunnable(int seconds, int startId) {
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                finishedTasksInTheLast60Sec.add("Finished Task: MyRun#" + startId);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyRun#" + startId + " end");
            }
        }, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(seconds));
    }

    private void sendBroadcast(List<String> finishedTasks) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("myServiceUpdate");
        intent.putExtra("finishedTasks", (ArrayList<String>)finishedTasks);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyService onCreate");
        es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        h.postDelayed(r, 60000);

    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        h.removeCallbacks(r);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyService onDestroy ");
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyService onStartCommand");
        readFlags(flags);
        int time = intent.getIntExtra("time", 1);
        if (time != -1) {
            MyRun mr = new MyRun(time, startId);
            es.execute(mr);
        } else stopSelf();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
        //return START_STICKY;
        //return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onBind");
        return null;
    }

    void readFlags(int flags) {
        if ((flags & START_FLAG_REDELIVERY) == START_FLAG_REDELIVERY)
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "START_FLAG_REDELIVERY");
        if ((flags & START_FLAG_RETRY) == START_FLAG_RETRY)
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "START_FLAG_RETRY");
    }

    class MyRun implements Runnable {
        int time;
        int startId;

        public MyRun(int time, int startId) {
            this.time = time;
            this.startId = startId;
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyRun#" + startId + " create");
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyRun#" + startId + " start, time = " + time);
            waitRunnable(time, startId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `ExecutorService` to store a queue of `Runnables` and perform them one at a time. Call `ExecutorService#submit` to add a `Runnable` to the queue.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Comment: But I wanna use the handler.postDelayed function in my waitRunnable() so he will finish after a certain amount of time from itself! With ExecutorService.submit I can queue Runnables but not my waitRunnable() which uses a postDelayed method!?

Comment: So maybe my question was just bad and I need to ask for queueing up postDelayed methods of a handler :)

Comment: You could have each `Runnable` call `waitRunnable` when it runs, that way each `Runnable` would start the next and they would have to run sequentially.

Comment: Thx a lot, this helped :)